# Yii Share models between two applications

Tags: php, yii

I've two web applications which are located on one server but on different domains (for example app A is administration and app B is client).

The problem is that I want to share models (ActiveRecords) from application A to be available in application B.

Is there any clever way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to make an alias in one app to the second ( And  from the 2nd to the 1st ;) ) using 
 `YiiBase::setPathOfAlias()`

Documentation:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#setPathOfAlias-detail

Comment: Well this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for :) I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just follow a few easy steps:

#### 1. Put your models in a shared directory

For example, if your current directory structure looks like this:

```
/www
    /application1
        /protected
            /models
    /application2
        /protected
            /models
```

Create another "shared" directory. It's a good idea to put some structure in there as well, in case you want to share more than just some models:

```
/www
    /application1
        /protected
            /models
    /application2
        /protected
            /models
    /shared
        /models
```

Put the active record models you want to share in `/www/shared/models`.

#### 2. Alias the shared directory in both applications

Go to your `main.php` configuration file in both applications and create an alias for the shared directory:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('shared','../shared/'); // or use an absolute path
```

#### 3. Import shared models

Still in your `main.php` configuration,  import your shared models:

```
'import'=>array(
    // ...existing imports here...
    'shared.models.*',
),
```

You can now directly refer to the shared classes anywhere in your application and Yii will load the appropriate classes automatically.

If you later add more directories to `/shared` then simply add corresponding lines to the `import` configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('applicationA','path/to/applicationA/protected');
```

Then when you making import in config:

```
'import' => array('applicationA.models.*'....
```

Now you will be able to use models from appA in appB.

Same can be done with modules, controllers and views. 
Views - viewPath
Modules - modulePath
Controllers - in index.php add

```
$app->setControllerPath('////protected/controllers');
```

Before `$app->run();`